# C# Multiple Same Forms, Different Values From SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-update

I got stuck because of a problem which I couldn't manage. The project is working on C# Winforms. There are multiple jobs on a list, and when a user selects one job another form is opened. On this form, user can start the job, or continue to the job from where he/she left. When the job is started, a timer starts, when user clicks to pause it stops and it's written to the database (MS SQL Update statement is used, passed time and the status of the job is written to the database) . When the user starts multiple (let's say 2 jobs) jobs, 2 same forms with different values are visible. So far so good, but when user starts both jobs in the same time it's  kind of binds values and the timer counts x2 times. In another words they're acting like one form and the counter counts multiple times according to the same number of forms.

Is there a way to differentiate multiple same forms between them? I hope you guys can understand my english, have a good day !!

Here's the code :

```
public partial class ClientPage : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    
    readonly Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    bool alreadyopened = false;
    public ClientPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }

    readonly SqlCNK NewConnection = new SqlCNK();

    private void ClientPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label8.Text = GlobalVeriables.ongorulensure;
        //Labellarda ilgili MPS ve İş Emri detaylarını göster
        label7.Text = GlobalVeriables.mamulstokkodu;
        label9.Text = GlobalVeriables.mpsno;           //SOME INFORMATION FOR THE USER
        label10.Text = GlobalVeriables.baslanansure;
        label11.Text = GlobalVeriables.mamuladi;
        button4.Visible = false;//FINISH BUTTON WILL BE VISIBLE WHEN USER STARTS THE JOB
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button2.ImageIndex = 3;
    }

    //GO BACK BUTTON OPERATIONS
    private void guna2ImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

        //IF THE JOB IS CONTINUING ALERT
        if (button4.Visible == true)
        {
            DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("JOB WILL BE STOPPED ARE U SURE?", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //STORE THE TIME
                timer2.Enabled = false;
                GlobalVeriables.status = "stopped";
                //WRITE ELAPSED TIME TO DB
                NewConnection.Connection();
                SqlCNK.connectSql.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = SqlCNK.connectSql; 
                GlobalVeriables.gecensure = GlobalVeriables.hours + ":" + GlobalVeriables.minutes;
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE CNKbaslananisler SET gecensure='"+GlobalVeriables.gecensure+"' where uniqueid='"+GlobalVeriables.selecteduniqueid+"'";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                foreach (Form frm in fc) //IF MAIN PAGE IS ALREADY OPENED DONT OPEN IT AGAIN
                {
                    //iterate through
                    if (frm.Name == "MainPage")
                    {
                        alreadyopened = true;
                    }
                }
                if (alreadyopened == false) 
                {
                    MainPage OperatorPage = new MainPage();
                    OperatorPage.Location = this.Location;
                    //OperatorPage.ChooseStartPage();
                    OperatorPage.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                    OperatorPage.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                    OperatorPage.Show();
                }

                GlobalVeriables.adminUser = false;
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //IF MAIN PAGE IS ALREADY OPENED DONT OPEN IT AGAIN
            foreach (Form frm in fc) 
            {
                //iterate through
                if (frm.Name == "MainPage")
                {
                    alreadyopened = true;
                }
            }

            if (alreadyopened == false)
            { 
             MainPage OperatorPage = new MainPage();
             OperatorPage.Location = this.Location;
             //OperatorPage.ChooseStartPage();
             OperatorPage.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
             OperatorPage.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
             OperatorPage.Show();
             
            }

            SqlCNK.connectSql.Close();
            GlobalVeriables.adminUser = false;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }

    //START BUTTON OPERATIONS
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GlobalVeriables.started == 0) 
        {
    //RESET THE TIMER AND START IT
            timer2.Stop();
            timer2.Start();
            timer2.Enabled = true;

            //POPUP
            PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
            popup.Image = Properties.Resources.information;
            popup.TitleText = "Bildirim";
            popup.ContentText = "MPS Başlatılmıştır";
            popup.Popup();

            statusLabel.Text = "STARTED";
            button4.Visible = true; // FINISH BUTTON IS ONLY VISIBLE WHEN THE JOB IS STARTED
            GlobalVeriables.started = 1; 
            button2.ImageIndex = 2; //START BUTTON IS CHANGED TO PAUSE BUTTON

            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;//BAŞLAMA süresini göster
            button2.ImageIndex = 2;
            //DELETE THE JOB FROM ASSIGNED JOBS AND ADD IT TO THE STARTEDJOBS TABLE 
            NewConnection.Connection();
            SqlCNK.connectSql.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = SqlCNK.connectSql;
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM ASSIGNEDJOBS WHERE uniqueid='" + GlobalVeriables.selecteduniqueid+"'";
            cmd.CommandText += "INSERT INTO STARTEDJOBS values('"+GlobalVeriables.mpsno+"','" + GlobalVeriables.artikelno +"','" + GlobalVeriables.selecteduniqueid + "','" + GlobalVeriables.mamulstokkodu + "','" + GlobalVeriables.atanantarih + "','"+GlobalVeriables.uretilecekmiktar+"','1','"+GlobalVeriables.operasyonaciklamasi+"','"+GlobalVeriables.opCode+"','" + GlobalVeriables.mamuladi + "','0','"+currentTime+"','"+GlobalVeriables.ongorulensure+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            label10.Text = currentTime.ToString();
            stopwatch.Start();
            
            
        }

        //STOP BUTTON OPERATIONS
        else if (GlobalVeriables.started == 1)
        {
            //POPUP
            PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
            popup.Image = Properties.Resources.information;
            popup.TitleText = "Bildirim";
            popup.ContentText = "MPS Duraklatılmıştır";
            popup.Popup();

            statusLabel.Text = "STOPPED";
            button2.ImageIndex = 3; //CONTINUE BUTTON WILL BE SHOWN 
            timer2.Enabled = false;
            GlobalVeriables.started = 2; //STORE THE SITUATION OF THE JOB 
            button4.Visible = false;

            Options secenekler = new Options();
            secenekler.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;//USER HAS TO STATE WHY HE/SHE STOPPED THE JOB
            secenekler.ControlBox = false;
            secenekler.ShowDialog();
            stopwatch.Stop();

            //TIME CALCULATION
            GlobalVeriables.PASSEDTIME = (GlobalVeriables.elapsedhrs * 3600 + GlobalVeriables.elapsedmnts * 60 + GlobalVeriables.elapsedscnds).ToString();

            //STORE THE PASSED TIME TO THE DATABSE
            NewConnection.Connection();
            SqlCNK.connectSql.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = SqlCNK.connectSql;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE STARTEDJOBS SET started='2', gecensure='"+GlobalVeriables.gecensure+"' WHERE uniqueid='"+GlobalVeriables.selecteduniqueid+"'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            SqlCNK.connectSql.Close();
        }

        else if (GlobalVeriables.started ==2)//IF THE JOB CONTINUES
        {
            //POPUP
            PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
            popup.Image = Properties.Resources.information;
            popup.TitleText = "Bildirim";
            popup.ContentText = "MPS Devam Ettiriliyor";
            popup.Popup();

            statusLabel.Text = "CONTINUING";
            button4.Visible = true;
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            GlobalVeriables.started = 1;// IT IS STARTED AGAIN
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button2.ImageIndex = 2; //SHOW THE PAUSE ICON
            stopwatch.Start();

            //STORE THE JOB IS CONTINUING TO THE DATABASE
            NewConnection.Connection();
            SqlCNK.connectSql.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = SqlCNK.connectSql;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE STARTEDJOBS SET started='1' WHERE uniqueid='" + GlobalVeriables.selecteduniqueid + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCNK.connectSql.Close();

            //TIME CALCULATIONS
            int total_seconds = Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVeriables.gecensure);
            GlobalVeriables.elapsedhrs = total_seconds / 3600;
            GlobalVeriables.elapsedmnts = total_seconds / 60 % 60;
            GlobalVeriables.elapsedscnds = total_seconds % 60;



        }
    }
    

    // WHEN FINISH BUTTON IS CLICKED
    private void guna2ImageButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        
        //SAVE FINISH TIME
        GlobalVeriables.endtime = GlobalVeriables.elapsedhrs.ToString() + "sa:" + GlobalVeriables.elapsedmnts.ToString()+"dk";

        DialogResult dresult = MessageBox.Show("ARE U SURE FINISHING THE JOB?", "Alert"
                          , MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dresult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.Hide();
            String elapsed = GlobalVeriables.elapsedhrs + "HRS" + GlobalVeriables.elapsedmnts+"MNTS";
            NewConnection.Connection();
            SqlCNK.connectSql.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = SqlCNK.connectSql;
            String current = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM startedjobs where uniqueid='"+GlobalVeriables.selecteduniqueid+"'";
            //Biten İşleri bitirilenisler havuzunda topla
            cmd.CommandText += "INSERT into endedjobs values(" +GlobalVeriables.mpsno+ ",'" + GlobalVeriables.artikelno + "','" + GlobalVeriables.selecteduniqueid + "','" + GlobalVeriables.mamulstokkodu + "','" + GlobalVeriables.operasyonaciklamasi + "','" + GlobalVeriables.opCode + "','" + GlobalVeriables.mamuladi + "','" + GlobalVeriables.gecensure + "','"+current+"','"+GlobalVeriables.uretilecekmiktar+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCNK.connectSql.Close();

            FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
            foreach (Form frm in fc) //IF MAIN PAGE IS ALREADY OPENED DONT OPEN IT AGAIN
            {
                //iterate through
                if (frm.Name == "MainPage")
                {
                    alreadyopened = true;
                }
            }

            if (alreadyopened == false)
            {
                MainPage OperatorPage = new MainPage();
                OperatorPage.Location = this.Location;
                OperatorPage.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                OperatorPage.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                OperatorPage.Show();
            }
        }
    }

    //TIME OPERATIONS
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalVeriables.elapsedscnds++;
        if (GlobalVeriables.elapsedscnds > 59)
        {
            GlobalVeriables.elapsedmnts++;
            GlobalVeriables.elapsedscnds = 0;
        }
        if (GlobalVeriables.elapsedmnts > 59)
        {
            GlobalVeriables.elapsedhrs++;
            GlobalVeriables.elapsedmnts = 0;
        }

        label13.Text = GlobalVeriables.elapsedhrs.ToString();
        label14.Text = GlobalVeriables.elapsedmnts.ToString();
        label15.Text = GlobalVeriables.elapsedscnds.ToString();

        

    }


    


   
}
```

Comment: "2 same forms with different values are visible" does that mean you show 2 different instances of the same form class?

Comment: " binds values and the timer counts x2 times" please post the code that contains the timer and where in which class the timer is declared

Comment: Desing some classes to handle the jobs, use new instances of the form as means of interact with the user as needed.

Comment: @MongZhu I didn't use instances I guess, I put the code btw. Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: @aamartin2k so I should use contructors and classes to do it?

Comment: I made the comment without seen the code. I've seen it now and stick to my guns. Don't mean to be rude, but you should think again your project. You have mixed in the same place database code, gui code, logic code. Do some reseach about SOLID and it will save you so many troubles in the future.

Comment: Some quick example: by using your own collection to store references to forms you avoid having to filter out "MainPage" from the others in the foreach loop.

Comment: Separate code dealing with data, database, timer in a model class that exposes properties. You the instantiate the model class and have an instance of your form databound to that model instance. Repeat instantiation as necessary. Do not use global variables. Use a data access layer to access database.

Comment: The SQL Server is multi-threaded so each query can execute on multiple threads.  When you try to do two queries at the same time the order is non going to be predictable.  You can run a query on a SQL Server and each time you run the data will come back in a different order so you need to always use an Order By to get data in same sequence.  So you have to make sure the two queries do not have any thing in common or make sure you are unique identification so the two queries are completely independent.